# Rexster extension with path parameters

Tags: tinkerpop, rexster

Is there any way to have path parameters in a Rexster extension, i.e. the equivalent of Jersey's `@PathParam`?

From what I could see from the sample extensions, only query params appear to be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to work with path parameters in Rexster.  You can however access the path and make programmatic decisions on that.  You can look at the [Frames Extension](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/tree/master/rexster-kibbles/frames-kibble) for an example of how to do it [here](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/blob/master/rexster-kibbles/frames-kibble/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/rexster/kibbles/frames/FramesExtension.java#L115).

The basic idea is to grab the `UriInfo` from the `RexsterResourceContext`.  From there you can reason about the path in your code.